# Assigning string and Int with If statement

Tags: c#, email, variables, smtpclient

Ok I have been searching for a solution for this but am stumped. I'm making an email client in C#. I can get around in c# but sometimes get caught up with syntax.

Heres my problem. I am trying to assign the smtpclient settings based on the user input of their email. I am getting a error on line 53 (use of unassigned local variable).

```
smtpclient smm = new smtpclient(s, p);
```

Here is my code:

```
        private void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the login info for the email
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(Euser.Text, Epass.Text);
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

        msg.To.Add(Toemail.Text);
        msg.From = new MailAddress(Euser.Text);
        msg.Subject = Subemail.Text;
        msg.Body = body.Text;

        string s;
        int p;

        if (Euser.Text.Contains("@gmail.com") == true)
        {
            s = "smtp.gmail.com";
            p = 587;
        }
        if (Euser.Text.Contains("@yahoo.com") == true)
        {
           s = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"; 
           p = 995;
        }
        if (Euser.Text.Contains("@live.com") == true)
        {
           s = "smtp.live.com"; 
           p = 587;
        }

        SmtpClient smm = new SmtpClient(s, p);

        smm.Credentials = nc;
        smm.EnableSsl = true;

        try
        {
            smm.Send(msg);
            MessageBox.Show("Emails Sent Successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error sending your emails");
        }
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Should I create a method for this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you would - what do you expect the values of `s` and `p` to be if none of those conditions are true? You won't have assigned any values, and C# doesn't let you read from local variables which aren't definitely assigned.

Comment: Sorry about that. Just updated the post. Error is Unassigned local variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give your variables a value in all situations. Right now, if none of your `if` tests are true, what do `s` and `p` end up being? They'd never be set to anything.

To avoid the error you can just initialize the variables with a default value:

```
string s = null;
int p = 0;
```

Or give them something more meaningful if it makes sense.

An alternative would be to use an `else` to capture everything else. However, you'd have to restructure your `if` statements into `else if`s (which would be better anyway. If you already found a match, you shouldn't have to keep testing for further matches):

```
if (test)
{
}
else if (test)
{
}
else if (test)
{
}
else
{
    s = null;
    p = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks itsme86. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont get into any of the IF, you have no value in s and p, so set a default value or put an ELSE